# Error in Accept-Encoding header in jdk 1.8.0_91

Tags: java, http, java-8, httpurlconnection, http-accept-encoding

I am making a `POST` call. The call is working on one system (say system1) and not working on the other system (say system2).

I am getting following error:

```
[2016-08-15 20:22:43.242] [qtp2024542466-14] [ERROR] [c.a.b.e.m.AbstractExceptionMapper] [Error executing rest API.Error Message: Illegal character(s) in message header field: Accept-Encoding:> Req: (POST //backend.morph.ai:8080/rest/panel/auth/signup?)@691675178 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request@293a202a
Ref id: 201608152022-695a6dc8-10f6-4382-ae93-de62c84fcc21] [javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Illegal character(s) in message header field: Accept-Encoding:
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:671)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:668)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:668)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:428)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:334)
    at com-------------------------Internal Class
    at com-------------------------Internal Class
    at com-------------------------Internal Class
    at com-------------------------Internal Class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:403)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1684)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
    at com-------------------------Internal Class
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character(s) in message header field: Accept-Encoding:
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.checkMessageHeader(HttpURLConnection.java:489)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.isExternalMessageHeaderAllowed(HttpURLConnection.java:459)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpURLConnection.java:3018)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestProperty(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.setOutboundHeaders(HttpUrlConnector.java:362)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.access$100(HttpUrlConnector.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector$4.getOutputStream(HttpUrlConnector.java:325)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:194)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commit(CommittingOutputStream.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.commitStream(OutboundMessageContext.java:816)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:545)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:329)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:254)
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

**Header**

I am sending following header on both systems: `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`

**Java versions**
system1:

```
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

system2:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

I also tried to check the source code where the error is thrown (check code of `checkMessageHeader` method):

`dk8-b91`: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/169451cf0cc5/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java

`jdk8-b51`: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/e865efbc7105/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java

In both the files the source code for `checkMessageHeader` is identical. Also source code is checking for `\n` and throwing error after checking some conditions, but only if `\n` is present. I don't have any `\n` in the key or value.

I am not able to understand what could be the issue? Or how to proceed?

Comment: Check the content of `Accept-Encoding`, and if possible add it in the question

Comment: I already added that in the question, see below shared stacktrace. Let me highlight it

Comment: Try removing the leading comma along with all the white spaces.

Comment: the leading comma I put here by mistake (now removing it). Let me try after removing spaces.

Comment: I tried removing spaces, the error is still coming.

Comment: Just leave `gzip` there, remove `deflate, br` see if that works.

Comment: But on `system1` this (`gzip, deflate, br`) is working. Its not like that I am sending the wrong Header value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121004/discussion-between-abhishek-gupta-and-11thdimension).

Comment: *How* are you setting this header?

Comment: @EJP I am setting it on Invocation.Builder class (javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder).

`WebTarget target = getWebTarget("enpointName");
Invocation.Builder request = keyTarget.request();
request.header("Accept-Encoding:", "gzip, deflate, br");`

Comment: I suppose, you should name the header key without a colon, but besides that, why don’t you use a clean `request.acceptEncoding("gzip", "deflate", "br")`?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for my case. The ':' character is creating the issue (at least in my case).

If I do the following:

headers.put("Authorization",Collections.singletonList("Bearer 123"));

It is ok.

So, I think in the original problem of this thread, instead of providing the key as "Accept-Encoding:" if "Accept-Encoding" is provided, the probably that may work.

Chrees!